# How can I create a handler, for dynamically created buttons, in the parent view controller?

Tags: swift, xcode6

I created a `subview` from the `ViewController`. In the `subview`, multiple buttons are created. When any of the created buttons are tapped, I want to call the function `buttonTapped()` in the parent `view controller`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var bestTeamEver = SFGiants(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: view.bounds.width, height: 40))
    view.addSubview(bestTeamEver)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


func buttonTapped(){

    NSLog("BUTTON INSIDE SFGIANTS TAPPPED")

    }
}


class SFGiants: UIView {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    for i in 0...10 {

        var new_x = i*44

        var button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: new_x, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

        // Call buttonTapped() in parent view controller
        button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)

        self.addSubview(button)

    }
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a customize init method and can pass reference to parent viewController and set that to button target.

```
init(frame: CGRect actionListener:UIViewController) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
 for i in 0...10 {

        var new_x = i*44

        var button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: new_x, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

        // Call buttonTapped() in parent view controller
        button.addTarget(actionListener, action: "buttonTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)

        self.addSubview(button)

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! This is a step in the right direction. Maybe I'm still doing something wrong, but only the first button created executes "buttonTapped" when tapped.